# Elasticsearch Delete Mapping Property

Tags: json, rest, lucene, elasticsearch

I am trying to figure out an approach to delete all entries for a specific property in an elasticsearch index and remove all type mappings for that property.

I have been looking at the following two doc pages: [put mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-put-mapping/) and [delete mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-delete-mapping/)

From second link:

> "Allow to delete a mapping (type) along with its data. The REST
>   endpoint is /{index}/{type} with DELETE method."

What I think I need is a `/{index}/{type}/{property}`?

Do I need to recreate the whole index to accomplish this, i.e. moving and manipulating data between types?

For Example, calling GET on the mapping:

```
curl -XGET 'http://.../some_index/some_type/_mapping'
```

result:

```
{
  "some_type": {
    "properties": {
      "propVal1": {
        "type": "double",
        "index": "analyzed"
      },
      "propVal2": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "keyword"
      },
      "propVal3": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

after this delete operation on `propVal3` would return:

```
curl -XGET 'http://.../some_index/some_type/_mapping'
```

result:

```
{
  "some_type": {
    "properties": {
      "propVal1": {
        "type": "double",
        "index": "analyzed"
      },
      "propVal2": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and all data for `propVal3` would be removed through the index.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can not do that. Just forget that this value exists... ;-)
If you really need to remove it, you will have to reindex your documents.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I feel I am going to need to do this. What is the best strategy for doing this via "reindexing"? I realize this is going to be a performance nightmare... but what strategy would you take here? Is moving to another type (removing property in process) and back again an option?

Comment: Created a followup to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159902/elasticsearch-reindex-or-flag-deleted-type-property

Comment: Why does the documentation say it is possible? Or did I misunderstand it?

Comment: Could you provide the link to the doc where we say that?

Answer (score 17):

You can use the new `_reindex` api for this, you could even PUT a new `_mapping` to the dest index before running the reindex so you can change the properties of the fields in your index.

To do a reindex and removing a property, you can do this:

```
POST /_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "twitter"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_twitter",
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.remove('whatever')"
  }
}
```

if you would use this in combination with the [_aliases API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) you can modify indexes without having any 'downtime'

Comment: This answer took me a while to find. But this is the only way I was able to completely delete a filed of null values in elastic. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It's not currently possible to remove a property from a mapping. In order to remove all values of a property from all records, you need to reindex all records with this property removed.

Comment: @TheRedPea using [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-reindex.html) for example or one of many reindex scripts available for elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add another approach for the case of "removing property from index".

```
POST pulse/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.remove(\"file_id\")",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose whats documents fields you will reindex to a new index. For example:

POST _reindex
{
"source": {
"index": "my-source-index",
"_source": ["host.hostname", "host.ip", "another_field"]
},
"dest": {
"index": "my-dest-index"
}
}

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-filter-source