# Remove a field from a Elasticsearch document

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to remove a field in all the documents indexed to Elasticsearch. How can I do it?

Comment: By default it's not possible, because right now Lucene doesn't support 
that. Basically you can only put or remove whole Lucene documents from 
Lucene indices.                                                                                                  1 Get the first version of your doc 
2 remove the field 
3 push this new version of your doc.

Comment: Thanks for sharing https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771354/8392866 Thiagofalcao. This is great!

Comment: The only way I could complete this was by remapping the index with the deleted field value. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/38874129/13543225

Answer (score 128, accepted):

What @backtrack told is true , but then there is a very convenient way of doing this in Elasticsearch.
Elasticsearch will abstract out the internal complexity of the deletion.
You need to use update API to achieve this -

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/type1/1/_update' -d '{
    "script" : "ctx._source.remove(\"name_of_field\")"
}'
```

You can find more documentation [here](https://qbox.io/blog/introduction-to-elasticsearch-scripting).

Note: As of Elastic Search 6 you are required to include a content-type header:

```
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Comment: What is the performance of this if you have a billion documents with this field?

Comment: The actual document will get removed and a new one will get added for each of such change.

Comment: Notice for ElasticSearch 5.0: you should use a named parameter instead of the hardcoded name. Parametes are faster and they won't break script's compilation limit. See [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html#prefer-params).

Comment: @VineethMohan will it also remove the mapping too ? so if i query test/type1/_mapping, will it show 'name_of_field' ?  
so basically, i want to remove and add the same filed name with diff type. Is it possible wit this ?

Comment: Additionally if you are referencing nested fields with hyphens, you can use `ctx._source[\"my-field\"].remove(\"subfield\")`.

Answer (score 54):

Elasticsearch added [`update_by_query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) in 2.3.  This experimental interface allows you to do the update against all the documents that match a query.

Internally elasticsearch does a scan/scroll to collect batches of documents and then update them like the bulk update interface.  This is faster than doing it manually with your own scan/scroll interface due to not having the overhead of network and serialization.  Each record must be loaded into ram, modified and then written.

Yesterday I removed a large field from my ES cluster.  I saw sustained throughput of 10,000 records per second during the update_by_query, constrained by CPU rather than IO.

Look into setting `conflicts=proceed` if the cluster has other update traffic, or the whole job will stop when it hits a `ConflictError` when one of the records is updated underneath one of the batches.

Similarly setting `wait_for_completion=false` will cause the update_by_query to run via the [tasks](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html) interface.  Otherwise the job will terminate if the connection is closed.

url:

```
http://localhost:9200/INDEX/TYPE/_update_by_query?wait_for_completion=false&conflicts=proceed
```

POST body:

```
{
  "script": "ctx._source.remove('name_of_field')",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "name_of_field"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As of Elasticsearch 1.43, inline [groovy scripting is disabled by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html).  You'll need to enable it for an inline script like this to work by adding `script.inline: true` to your config file.

Or upload the groovy as a script and use the `"script": { "file": "scriptname", "lang": "groovy"}` format.

Comment: What I don't know yet, is how to reclaim the field_data space used by that field.  Hoping a rolling restart will cause the ordinals to be reloaded.

Comment: The body needed a slight modification, but otherwise this works perfectly. I had to wrap the script in a JSON object, probably because the API changed a bit.

Comment: If my field is part of the array(for e.g [{"name":"test"},{"name":"test1"}] )and I don't know the index of the array for that field So how I can delete the field by using above query.                                         Please Help me into this?

Comment: @sayed-abolfazl-fatemi thanks for your clean-up edit to the code.

Comment: This was awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 47):

You can use **[_update_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html)**

### Example 1

**index: my_index**

**field: user.email**

```
POST my_index/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.user.remove('email')",
    "query" : {
        "exists": { "field": "user.email" }
    }
}
```

### Example 2

**index: my_index**

**field: total_items**

```
POST my_index/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.remove('total_items')",
    "query" : {
        "exists": { "field": "total_items" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hii, I tried the exact same approach as you mentioned here but it didn't seem working  for me.  I am a newbie in this area. I have an unwanted field in my index say index name "test_xyz". This contains almost 155154 documents. I want to remove an unwanted field from my index. This is how my index pattern look like in json format {A : {B : {C: } } }. I basically want to remove the B - means C will be automatically remove from my index.  In order to do that, I used your first idea. Put A as user, B as email. Can you please help me to solve this?

Comment: Hi @MaunilVyas,

It should work:

    POST my_index/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
    {
        "script" : "ctx._source.A.remove('B')",
        "query" : {
            "exists": { "field": "A.B" }
        }
    }

If it does not work, you need to reindex data with target index with correct mapping.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes it is working now. I did some minor mistakes!

Comment: Great! :-) Welcome.

Comment: hello, is this operation also deleting the field from mapping? It is not, right?

Comment: Hi @srcnaks in order to remove from mapping, you need to reindex from source index to target index.

Comment: This answer helped me understand deletion of *nested* fields. Thanks!

Comment: So simple, yet so effective! Thanks a lot, mate!

Answer (score 14):

The previous answers did'nt worked for me.

I had to add the keyword "inline":

```
POST /my_index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.remove(\"myfield\")"
  },
  "query" : {
      "exists": { "field": "myfield" }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

By default it's not possible, because right now Lucene doesn't support that. Basically you can only put or remove whole Lucene documents from Lucene indices.

1. Get the first version of your doc
2. remove the field
3. push this new version of your doc

This answer is valid for version < ES 5.

Comment: @ThomasDecaux, Many thanks. I have answered in 2015 and i know that  ES has the ability now.  Once again thank you for poining it.

Comment: @ThomasDecaux - Indeed that is true. thanks for your valuable feedback. I just added the version.

Answer (score 3):

For those who stick to [bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/docs-bulk.html), the alternative to achieve deletion on field(s) of document(s) is to provide extra script in the [`update` action payload](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/docs-bulk.html#bulk-update) of a bulk API call.

The command part is the same as described in official documentation :

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson"  -H "Accept: application/json; indent=4;" \
     --data-binary   '@es_bulk_edit_data.json'  --request POST \
     "http://YOUR_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:PORT_NUM/OPTIONAL_INDEX/OPTIONAL_TYPE/_bulk?pretty"
```

In the request body file, you may need to use 2 payloads for the same document, one of them is for creating, updating fields, the other is for deleting fields by script, which may be like this:

```json
// assume you attempt to add one field `artist`, update one field `num_views`,
// and delete one field `useless` in the document with type t1 and ID 123
{"update": {"_type": "t1", "_id": "123"}}
{"doc": {"artist": "new_artist", "num_views": 67}}
{"update": {"_type": "t1", "_id": "123"}}
{"script": {"source": "ctx._source.remove(params.del_field_name)", "lang":"painless", "params":{"del_field_name": "useless"}}}
```

Note :

- In bulk API, `doc` section cannot be placed with `script` section in the same payload, ElasticSearch  seems to refuse to process such payload structure and return error response `400 bad request` and reason message would be `Validation Failed: 1: can't provide both script and doc;`. That is why I separate deletion  and all other operations in 2 payloads.
- these are tested on version 5.6 and 6.6, should also get the same result in latest version (v7.10)

Answer (score 3):

```
PUT /products/_update/1
{
  "docs" :{
    "price": 12,
    "quantity": 3,
    "in_stock": 6
  }
}

Now if I need to remove "quantity" then:

POST products/_update/1
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.remove(\"quantity\")"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add to the previous answers that **after deleting the field, the size of the index will not change**. will have to create a new index or use _reindex api.

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/_reindex?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
 "source": {
   "index": "old-index"
 },
 "dest": {
   "index": "new-index"
}}

'
```

Comment: This is not true, after deleting a certain deal of document segments will get merged  and disk space is freed. The only thing that remains there is the field in schema.