# ElasticSearch IO How to remove id from JSON document before writing

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an Apache Beam streaming job which reads data from Kafka and writes to ElasticSearch using ElasticSearchIO.

The issue I'm having is that messages in Kafka already have `key` field, and using `ElasticSearchIO.Write.withIdFn()` I'm mapping this field to document `_id` field in ElasticSearch.

Having a big volume of data I don't want the `key` field to be also written to ElasticSearch as part of `_source`.

Is there an option/workaround that would allow doing that?

Comment: is using logstash an option?

Comment: are you open to a solution that is not using Beam? For example with Kafka Connect you can easily drop fields

Comment: I've restricted to usage of Apache Beam and ElasticSearch only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a ticket in [Apache Beam JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6168) describing this issue.

For now the original issue can not be resolved as part of indexation process using Apache Beam API.

The workaround that Etienne Chauchot, one of the maintainers, proposed is to
have separate task which will clear indexed data afterwords.

See [Remove a field from a Elasticsearch document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002215/remove-a-field-from-a-elasticsearch-document) for example.

For the future, if someone also would like to leverage such feature, you might want to follow the linked ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Ingest API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest-apis.html) and the [remove processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/remove-processor.html) you´ll be able to solve this pretty easy only using your elasticsearch cluster. You can also [simulate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/simulate-pipeline-api.html) ingest pipeline and the results.

I´ve prepared a example which will probably cover your case:

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "description": "remove id form incoming docs",
    "processors": [
      {"remove": {
        "field": "id",
        "ignore_failure": true
      }}
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
      {"_source":{"id":"123546", "other_field":"other value"}}
    ]
}
```

You see, there is one test document containing a filed "id". This field is not present in the response/result anymore:

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {
      "doc" : {
        "_index" : "_index",
        "_type" : "_type",
        "_id" : "_id",
        "_source" : {
          "other_field" : "other value"
        },
        "_ingest" : {
          "timestamp" : "2018-12-03T16:33:33.885909Z"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: is this API is a part of Apache Beam ?

Comment: No, it's pure elasticsearch. In such a way you'll be able to send whaterver you have and preprocess each document before indexing