# Delete only fields from all the documents that match my criteria

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless, amazon-elasticsearch

To delete any field with value from all the documents without deleting the whole document from the Elasticsearch index usually I use `_update_by_query` API call with `script`

**For Ex:** on **my_properties** index I want to delete all the fields e.g (key=>value) from all the documents where it exists. Using below query I'm able to delete all the **feed** field where it is exists but it this case the feed field is **text/string** type

**Index**: my_properties

**Field**: feed

**Type**: text

**Example Value on feed:**  `feed: ["AB-1234"]`

```
POST my_properties/_update_by_query?refresh&conflicts=proceed
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.remove('feed')",
    "query" : {
        "exists": { "field": "feed" }
    }
}
```

My main problem is when my field type is **nested** instead of **text/string**

**Index**: my_properties

**Field**: feed_v2

**Type**: nested

**Example Value on feed_v2:**  `feed_v2: [{"feed":12},{"id":["AB-9999"]}]`

**Approach 1:**

```
POST my_properties/_update_by_query?refresh&conflicts=proceed
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.remove('feed_v2')",
    "query" : {
        "exists": { "field": "feed_v2" }
    }
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
POST my_properties/_update_by_query?refresh&conflicts=proceed
{
    "script" : "ctx._source.feed_v2.remove('feed')",
    "query" : {
        "exists": { "field": "feed_v2.feed" }
    }
}
```

Nothing works, Am I missing something? Not sure but my guess is-

```
"query" : {"exists": { "field": "feed_v2" }}
```

> query **exists** doesn't work **same way with nested type field** that's why it
>   doesn't find anything while trying delete on `nested` type field

As per the Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771354/1138192 It should work for me but alas it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch has a concept of [Nested Datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), and for that only [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) would come to help. Basically your exists query would be in the below form:

### Nested Query to check if field Exists:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "feed_v2",
      "query": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "feed_v2.feed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You are looking for query that would help you delete a nested field from a nested document for which I've come up with the below script.

How nested documents differ from normal documents, according to this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html) is, *each nested object is indexed as a hidden separate document* hence the query that you are making use of, doesn't work.

### Update by query script for nested document to delete a field

This is for scenario you only want to delete `feed` i.e. `field_v2.feed` but you would want to preserve rest of the `field_v2` fields.

```
POST resumes/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": """
      for(int i=0; i<ctx._source.field_v2.size(); i++)
      {
        HashMap myKV = ctx._source.field_v2.get(i);
        if(myKV.get(params.key_ref)!=null){
          myKV.remove(params.key_ref);
        }
      }
    """,
    "params": {
      "key_ref": "feed"
  }}
}
```

Hope this helps!