# How to remove unwanted attributes from a document in an index

Tags: elasticsearch

How to remove unwanted attributes containing values from a document in an index in Elasticsearch

We created `additionalattr1, additionalattr2` in an index by mistake and they don't have a mapping either, what would be the best way to remove these in production.

additionalattr1 is a nested attribute, but mistakenly created in a flat structure within the document

```
"pi.ei.additionalattr1" : "Finance / CA / CS/ CFA / Others",
"pi.ei.additionalattr2" : "Finance",
```

Comment: This could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002215/remove-a-field-from-a-elasticsearch-document

Answer (score 0):

the only way to remove these is to reindex your data. this can be done by;

1. an _update script as YLR mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69258135/how-to-remove-unwanted-attributes-from-a-document-in-an-index#comment122413285_69258135)
2. a _reindex into a new index
3. or from your source data, outside of Elasticsearch